Showing that a particular function is holomorphic
Here is the problem: I have a diffeomorphism $F: \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^m \to \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^m$ over the projection $\mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^m \to \mathbb{C}^m$, so in other words, $\operatorname{pr}_2 \circ F = \operatorname{pr}_2$. In particular, I can write $F(z_1, \ldots, z_n, t_1, \ldots, t_m) = (F_1(z, t), \ldots, F_n(z, t), t_1, \ldots, t_m)$. Suppose I know that $F$ is holomorphic in the $t$ variables. Do I also know that $G = F^{-1}$ is holomorphic in the $t$ variables?
For context, I am trying to show the holomorphicity of the variation of a complex structure under certain conditions.
Edit: I realize that the domains may be too restrictive since we are working with holomorphic functions; instead of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C^m}$, consider instead simply connected open subsets of $\mathbb{C}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^m$.

No, and here's an simple explicit counterexample. Let $m = n = 1$. Let $F(z, t) = (\overline{z} + t, t)$. This has inverse $G(z, t) = (\overline{z} - \overline{t}, t)$, which is visibly non-holomorphic in $t$.
Let's examine more generally why we should not expect holomorphicity. Let $p$ be a point in the domain and let $F(p) = q$. Treating the $z_i, t_i$ as functions of two real variables, the total derivative of $F$ at $p$ is of the form
$$F'(p) = \begin{pmatrix}
M & 0 \\
N & I_{2m}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
Since $F$ is a diffeomorphism, $M$ is invertible. The fact that $F$ is holomorphic with respect to the $t_i$ means that $N$ is a $2m \times 2n$ matrix comprised of $2 \times 2$ blocks satisfying the Cauchy-Riemann equations; that is, of the form $$\begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$$ for real numbers $a, b$.
The total derivative of $G$ at $q$ is the inverse of $F'(p)$. This is
$$F'(p)^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}
M^{-1} & 0 \\
-NM^{-1} & I_{2m}
\end{pmatrix}.$$
$G$ is holomorphic in the $t_i$ only if the $2 \times 2$ blocks of $-NM^{-1}$ satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations for all $q$. Since we have no control over $M$, we should not expect this to occur. In the counterexample I presented, we have $N = I_{2}$ and $M = \begin{pmatrix}1 &0 \\
0 & -1\end{pmatrix}$, so that $-NM^{-1} = \begin{pmatrix}-1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$ fails the Cauchy-Riemann equations.
